# Is there a bot or service that buys a diversified portfolio of altcoins on a schedule?

Tags: altcoin

Is there a service or a script that just buys a mix of altcoins on a set schedule, like every week? Instead of trading, I just want to buy the top 20 coins by highest volume every week regardless of price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to modify [zenbot](https://github.com/carlos8f/zenbot) to do this. I have not used it , please use it at your own risk. It will essentially hook you up to one of the exchanges. You will need to figure out the top 10 ,perhaps using an external service or one of the API's for volume. All in all , i feel it is a risky proposition in a highly volatile market.